# Android Studio 3.3.2 kotlin Compiler Warning

Tags: android, kotlin, compilation, shrinkresources

I am using,

```
 Android Studio Version - 3.3.2
 minSdkVersion 19
 targetSdkVersion 27
```

Kotling plugin :

```
 apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
 apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
 apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

kotlin build file :

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
```

In top level build-gradle

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.1'
```

My Issue is Its giving me Lots of Kotlin Compiler Warning.

I have not issue with this warning but I want to add,

```
shrinkResources true
minifyEnabled true
```

in my application, but due to warning this giving me an error to solve warning first.

Please see my number of warning in screen shot, and if any have having solutions of it then please give ans here.

[image]

**Edit**

Following is my build.gradle file

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
 apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
 apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
 apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'


 android {
 compileSdkVersion 27
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "10.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {

  release {
        debuggable false
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug {
        debuggable true
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

      compileOptions {
      sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
      targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
      } 

      dexOptions {
      // Prevent OutOfMemory with MultiDex during the build phase
      javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
      }

      dataBinding {
         enabled = true
      }
}

kapt {
     generateStubs = true
}



  dependencies {
      implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
      implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
      implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
      implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
      implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
      implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
      testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
       androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'

       implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
       implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
       implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.39.0'
       implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:rx2-android-networking:1.0.2'

       implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.3.0'
       implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.3.0'
       implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
       implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
       implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
       implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
       implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1'
       implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.8'

       implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'
       implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'

       implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
       implementation project(':multipleimageselect')
       implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
// location
       implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
       implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
       annotationProcessor 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.4'

       implementation project(':library_slider')
       implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'

       implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
       annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
       implementation 'com.flurry.android:analytics:11.5.0@aar'
       implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'
       implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'
       implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:1.7.10'

 }
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: if you add build.gradle file as code it be helpful

Comment: Hello @Radesh I add my full build.gradle file

Comment: @Topsy,i have similar error Also ,AS>3.4RC1 Kotlin plugin>1.3.21

Comment: @engmms please inform if you found any solutions.

Comment: @Topsy,OK I will inform you

Comment: @Radesh Check my file ?